# JavaScript equivalent to Membership.GetUser()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using ASP.NET Membership Provider JavaScript library to authenticate users using the following:

```
Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.login(...)
```

And to check for their login status I use:

```
Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.get_isLoggedIn()
```

But is there a way to get the User object through JavaScript? I can easily get it on server-side using:

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();
```

But I am looking for a way to do the above in JavaScript (if possible).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.Net, but if you can't find other way, you could expose a service and request a serialized form of it, in JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serialize the data to a Javascript variable.

(Warning: Typed on-the-fly.  Didn't feel like logging into work to run this through the editor.)

```
// Copy the important user fields over.

var UserInfo = new {
  field1 = "field1"
};

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
<script>
  var userInfo = <%= serializer.Serialize(UserInfo ) %>
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what we ended up doing. Thanks.